# How to make abstract check for enum inside of default method of interface?

Tags: java, enums, interface, implements

I'm making a mod for Minecraft and trying to register multiple items using enums and one shared interface that will register all items provided when called, but I don't know how to go about the `for` loop, because the interface doesn't know what implemented it and I can't describe it too

this is my code:

```java
MaterialState.java
public interface MaterialState {
    default void register() {
        for (T material: this.values()) { 
            // I suppose that "this" is an enum that implements MaterialState, 
            // and "T" is the enum constant of this

            // todo some functionality
        }
    };
}

BasicStates.java
public enum BasicStates implements MaterialState {
    ingot, dust, gem, ore;
}

ItemRegistry.java
@EventListener
public void registerItems(ItemRegistryEvent event) {
    BasicStates.register()
}
```

Comment: Is `register` supposed to be a static method?

Comment: No, static methods don't have "this"

Comment: And I want "this" to be enum so that i can call `.values()` on it

Comment: But why are you trying to call it as `BasicStates.register()`? That's how you call a static method.

Comment: and it wouldn't work with default method? I'm not calling interface

Comment: You can't call any non static method like that, so it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: Is this possible with static method then?

Comment: You can't override a static method so using interface wouldn't make sense.

Comment: ok, i think i can just make util then, outside of interface, that will take enum as argument, and this shouldn't be too hard